# SAP ABAP CDS View Performance

Tags: abap, hana, cds

I haven't seen SAP document this anywhere but this seems to be how it works - someone please correct me if I am wrong.

ABAP code that does a select from a CDS view:
SELECT * FROM z_workorder_status
INTO TABLE @DATA(gt_wrk_stat)
WHERE vendor = @my_vendor.

The WHERE clause does not execute until AFTER all data is fetched from the CDS view, correct?  In other words, you must pass vendor as a CDS view parameter for the CDS view to use it as a filter.  It is not smart enough to use the WHERE clause as a filter inside the CDS view, correct?

I've run traces that seem to show this behavior.  To avoid huge result sets, CDS views should have a parameter for key values - vendor or plant or company code or date range...  Otherwise, CDS view brings back huge result set then where clause filters it down at the very end.(If you are lucky.  If you are unlucky, CDS view reaches system memory limit)

Comment: This seems to be rather a statement than a question. To allow others to review your analysis, I recommend sharing the trace results.

Answer (score 4):

No, your understanding is not correct. Whether the where clause can be directly considered or not in CDS selection is depending on how the CDS view is built. Here CDS selection do have concept 'Filter Push Down', meaning directly considering the filtering in HANA DB.
Please check this blog to get more ideas: https://blogs.sap.com/2018/12/20/safeguard-performance-of-abap-cds-views-part-3-rules-for-good-performance-of-cds-views/ .